# How to implement a "block" (first introduced by roam research) in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, org-roam

If you are familiar with roam research, you may know that it consists of `page` and `block`.

Relate it back to org-mode terms: `page` is equivalent to file, but there is no one-to-one mapping from `block` to either header or item in org mode.

`block` is a lot more flexible than header and item because `block` can be treated as header or item, depending on how one uses it.

The differences of `block` and header is as follows:

1. Content in header and items must be within 1 line. Content of a `block` can contain all characters: there is no restriction on its content.
2. header and items are used differently, as a results, functionality and use case differs. A `block`, on the other hand, can have functionality of header and items. (I am not sure why there should be distinction between the two in the first place).

To summarize, one can think of a `block` as a superset of header and items with additional flexibility.

*The question is: how to implement concept of `block` (first introduced by roam research) in org mode?*

To cut it short, block-like functionality can be implemented in org-mode by removing constraint of what header should and shouldn't contain, but all I want for now is to allow header to contain org-babel block.

This is to test whether this can be implemented at all given the known limitation of org mode.

This is the only reason I cannot move notes from roam research to org mode. (and its variant e.g. org-roam, org-brain) because none of them has a concept of `block`.

Comment: I think this topic should be post in [Org mail list](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-mailing-list.html)

Comment: ... or on the Reddit emacs site.